# Comboboxes (HTML, PHP)

Tags: php, combobox, forms

I need help regarding one combobox dependent on another combobox.

I have 2 combo fields in my form, one is of schools and other is of class. Every school has specific class and both are stored in databases. I have to pick the value of school from database (school table) and after selecting it 2nd combo box will show the classes related to the specific school.

After selecting these values I have to store them in database too.

Comment: What do you mean by `After selecting these values i have to store them in database too`?

Comment: Rather, are you having trouble retrieving the data and don't know how to do it? How are your SQL tables layed out?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Using javascript:

   1. You can use Javascript + Ajax to dynamicly get the second box's datasource, create an array and set the combobox's items.
   2. You can load the options that you want in array (using php when the page is created)

   In both ways you have an array(s) for every option from first combobox (two dimential array - first index is for the choices in first combobox and second is the index of item that will be added to second combobox). Then you use

   document.getElementById("DropDownList").options.add(opt);

to add the items in second combobox, when the value of the first is changed.

2 . Every time the value of the first combobox is changed, you can call submit() for the form, and then using php to fill second one (depending on 1st one's value).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have assume database configuration is correct and table as you haven't provided db detail.

Table1:school

### Field          type   detail

schoolid      int(11)   primary key
schoolname    varchar(50)
detail        varchar(50)

Table2:class

### Field         type   detail

class_id     int(11)   primary key 
classname     varchar(50)
schoolid      int(11)

add sample data in above db tables.
set database configuration as following line

$sConn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sajeda45")

localhost is hostname
root is dbusername
sajeda45 is dbpassword
imagedb is databasename

set above database parameter in following script and you have result what you want

```
<?php

        $sConn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sajeda45")
        or die("Couldn't connect to database server");
        $dConn = mysql_select_db("imagedb", $sConn);

        function getSchollList()
        {
            $schoolList = array();

            $result = mysql_query("select schoolid,schoolname from school") or die("Couldn't school list");

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    $id=$row['schoolid'];
                    $schoolList["".$id.""]  =$row['schoolname'];    
            }

            return $schoolList;
        }

        function getClassList($schoolId)
        {
            $classList = array();

            $result = mysql_query("select classname from class  where schoolid=$schoolId") or die("Couldn't class list");

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    $classList[]    =$row['classname']; 
            }
            return  $classList;
        }
    ?>

<html>
<title>Test Example</title> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function redirectForClass(schoolName)
            {
                    window.location="stackoverflow1.php?school="+schoolName;
            }
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $schoolList = getSchollList();
        $schoolId = isset($_GET['school']) ? $_GET['school']:0;
        $classList =  getClassList($schoolId); 
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="handler.php">

            School:
            <select name="school" onchange="redirectForClass(this.value);">
                <option value="0">--select school--</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($schoolList as $school_Id => $school){
                ?>      
                    <option value="<?php echo $school_Id; ?>" <?php if($school_Id==$schoolId) echo "SELECTED"; ?>><?php echo $school; ?></option>
                <?php   
                }
                ?>  
                </select>
                <br/><br/>
                    Class:
            <select name="class" >
                <option value="">--select Class--</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($classList as $class){
                ?>      
                    <option value="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $class; ?></option>
                <?php   
                }
                ?>  
                </select>
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form> 

</body>
</html> 
<?php

?>
```